# How to customise the numbering system of subequations with IEEEtranstools?

Tags: xetex, ieeetran

I'm using `IEEEtrantools`'s `IEEEeqarray`, and in there I can print sublabeled equations like

```
x^2   (1a)
y^2   (1b)
```

with:

```
 \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  x & = & y \IEEEyessubnumber \\
  z & = & b \IEEEyessubnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

However -- I need to have first subnumber to be `m`, second `b`:

```
x^2   (1m)
y^2   (1b)
```

So I read the source of `IEEEtrantools.sty` and here's the best I come up with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Test!}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  x & = & y \renewcommand\theIEEEsubequation{\theequation{m}} \IEEEyessubnumber \\
  z & = & b \renewcommand\theIEEEsubequation{\theequation{b}} \IEEEyessubnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

I compiles, but doesn't work. Any way to achieve that? `IEEEeqarray` is a must for me.

My question is: custom list to subnumber strings means that the default subnumber strings list is `a`, `b`, `c`,... while I need to have a custom list: `m`, `b`,... (for the problem at hand I need only two).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it: create a custom numbering system, called `\mynumsys` here, to be used in a local redefinition of `\theIEEEsubequation`. You could build on the my definition of `\mynumsys` to add more symbols, if needed.

Note: I got rid of most of your preamble tweaks because they were not directly related to the question. Putting them back in the code should not invalidate my solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\makeatletter
\def\mynumsys#1{\expandafter\@mynumsys\csname c@#1\endcsname}% LaTeX
\def\@mynumsys#1{%
  \ifnum#1=0%
    \@ctrerr% 
  \else\ifnum#1=1%
      m%
    \else\ifnum#1=2%
       b%
     \else
        \@ctrerr%
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\subsection{Test!}
{
\def\theIEEEsubequation{\theequation\mynumsys{IEEEsubequation}}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  x & = & y \renewcommand\theIEEEsubequation{\theequation{m}} \IEEEyessubnumber \\
  z & = & b \renewcommand\theIEEEsubequation{\theequation{b}} \IEEEyessubnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  x & = & y \renewcommand\theIEEEsubequation{\theequation{m}} \IEEEyessubnumber \\
  z & = & b \renewcommand\theIEEEsubequation{\theequation{b}} \IEEEyessubnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually I get `c` and `d` for a second pair or equations -- when compiling with either `xelatex` or `pdflatex`. Also -- it looks like there's no need for `renewcommand` anymore. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Take, e.g., \fnsymbol, name a copy of it, e.g., \mysymbol, define proper symbols, then change arabic counter in your definition to mysymbol.

**Edit** (alas, Kindle is not a good tool for longer posts)

In the following example `alph` counter was replaced by a new one. If you need both, some additional work is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
%\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
%\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
%\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
%\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
%\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}


\section{Test!}


\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  x & = & y  \\
  z & = & b 
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  x & = & y \IEEEyessubnumber \\
  z & = & b \IEEEyessubnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\makeatletter
\let\oldalph\alph
\let\old@alph\@alph
\def\alph#1{\expandafter\@alph\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@alph#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or m\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or j\or
   k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or s\or t\or u\or v\or w\or x\or
    y\or z\else\@ctrerr\fi}
\makeatother

Changed

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  x & = & y  \\
  z & = & b 
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  x & = & y \IEEEyessubnumber \\
  z & = & b \IEEEyessubnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  x & = & y \IEEEyessubnumber \\
  z & = & b \IEEEyessubnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}


%\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
%  x & = & y \renewcommand\theIEEEsubequation{\theequation{m}} \IEEEyessubnumber \\
%  z & = & b \renewcommand\theIEEEsubequation{\theequation{b}} \IEEEyessubnumber
%\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete solution.

Comment: You're better off creating a new numbering system than overwriting `\alph`.